# Pandas: how to get the rows that has the maximum value_count on a column grouping by another column as a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three columns in a pandas dataframe, `Date`, `Hour` and `Content`. **I want to get the hour in a day when there is the most content of that day.** I am using `messages.groupby(["Date", "Hour"]).Content.count().groupby(level=0).tail(1)`. I don't know what `groupby(level=0)` is doing here. It outputs as follows-

```
Date        Hour
2018-04-12  23       4
2018-04-13  21      43
2018-04-14  9        1
2018-04-15  23      29
2018-04-16  17       1
                    ..
2020-04-23  20       1
2020-04-24  22       1
2020-04-25  20       1
2020-04-26  23      32
2020-04-27  23       3
```

This is a pandas series object, and my desired `Date` and `Hour` columns are `MultiIndex` here. If I try to convert the `MultiIndex` object to dataframe using `pd.DataFrame(most_active.index)`, `most_active` being the output of the previous code, it creates a dataframe of tuples as below-

```
                    0
0    (2018-04-12, 23)
1    (2018-04-13, 21)
2     (2018-04-14, 9)
3    (2018-04-15, 23)
4    (2018-04-16, 17)
..                ...
701  (2020-04-23, 20)
702  (2020-04-24, 22)
703  (2020-04-25, 20)
704  (2020-04-26, 23)
705  (2020-04-27, 23)
```

But I need two separate columns of `Date` and `Hour`. What is the best way for this?

Comment: If you do not provide column name(s) in the `groupby` method, you'll have to provide a value to the `level` parameter, which is the level of your dataframe index. If you do code like you did (`level=0`), I think you'll group by Date only, once you have a MultiIndex dataframe with Date as level 0. Also, if you want to run `tail(1)` in the groupby, make sure to `sort_values()` first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit because I misunderstood your question**

First, you have to count the total content by date-hour, just like you did:

```
df = messages.groupby(["Date", "Hour"], as_index=False).Content.count()
```

Here, I left the groups in their original columns by passing the parameter `as_index=False`.

Then, you can run the code below, provided in the original answer:

Supposing you have unique index IDs (if not, just do `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`), you can use `idxmax` method in `groupby`. It will return the index with the biggest value per group, then you can use them for slicing the dataframe.

For example:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Date', 'Hour'])['Content'].idxmax()]
```

As an alternative (without using groupby), you can first sort the values in descending order, them remove the Date-Hour duplicates:

```
df.sort_values('Content', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Date', 'Hour'])
```

Finally, you get a `MultiIndex` with the `set_index()` method:

```
df.set_index(['Date','Hour'])
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but neither of them works as intended, Your second code tries to sort by `Content` which is a string field, and first code gives a `ValueError`, and nothing else. Maybe I have not stated this clearly in my question.

Comment: In fact, I misunderstood your question. I've edited the answer, adding a first chunk to get the counts (like you did), then a last one to get a `MultiIndex`. Pls let me know if it works.